# Who i can customize start date and end date to DataPicker in NG-Zorro

Tags: javascript, angular, datepicker

Ng zorro allows you to have a component where you can mark the start date and end date.
Is there a way to make the start date or end date non-mandatory?
Thank you.

I use this code

```
<nz-range-picker [nzFormat]="dateFormat"></nz-range-picker>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using two different inputs:

```html
<nz-date-picker [nzFormat]="dateFormat"></nz-date-picker>
<nz-date-picker [nzFormat]="dateFormat"></nz-date-picker>
```

All available attributes here: https://ng.ant.design/components/date-picker/en#api

Comment: ok but how i can verify if end date is grater then start date?

Comment: You can use attribute [nzDisabledDate]="disabledDate". Check this demo: https://github.com/NG-ZORRO/ng-zorro-antd/blob/master/components/date-picker/demo/disabled-date.ts